# How to rollback to some previous state of a MySQL DB *quickly*?

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on projects that make heavy use of the MySQL database. While debugging, I often encounter the problem of reverting to a previous state of the database. I.e.:

1. Prepare input data, start a program under the debugger.
2. Program makes changes in the database (here, I may don't know exactly which changes the program makes because of large project size).
3. Probably, I find some errors in code. If so, correct them and go to p. 1.

Because the program's behaviour may depend on data in the DB, at the step 3 I often need to roll the DB back to the initial state manually.

So, the question is: is there any way how to "wrap" each debugging iteration into something like transaction or apply some another tool in order to (a) the program can be run without limitations (i.e., this tool must not break the program's work) and (b) I can revert the DB to some initial state as quickly and simply as possible?

I do know about the `mysqldump`, but its using requires some significant time on each debugging iteration. So, I'd like to know, if there is some way which will be more lightweight than the `mysqldump`.

Comment: Reverting back to a previous change would require either a transaction or knowing exactly what you have changed and reversing the changes. Depending on the extent of changes and the time required to run the code, neither may be a viable option. Typically you would restore the test dataset from a backup / migration script / sql file / different database or just use a container with a pre-initialised mysql image.

Comment: "*Probably, I find some errors in code*" Is this being run on the production database? Do you have a test/staging environment with its own database?

Comment: @Schwern, all of it is about the development environment.

Comment: If it's the dev environment and preserving the data doesn't matter, drop and recreate just the schema between runs. Use [`mysqldump --nodata`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data), but you should have a clean copy of the database schema checked into your code. This should be part of your [schema migration tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration).